# Google group error 291 during join request

Tags: google-groups, email, mailing-list

I'm trying to join the [google group 'bup-list'](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/bup-list) and send an email to `bup-list+subscribe@googlegroups.com` and received a confirmation email which prompted me to open a link with a token in the URL which constantly fails due to

```
An error (#291) occured while communicating with the server.
```

asking me to enter an email address to subscribe. Entering the same address and pressing the subscribe button results in another confirmation email with a different token being sent which causes the same error. I reproduced this in Firefox 61.0.1 and Chromium 68.0.3440.75 on Ubuntu 18.04. I verified that the URL is copied and pasted correctly.

I'm following different solutions from [How can I subscribe to a Google mailing list with a non-Google e-mail address?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-can-i-subscribe-to-a-google-mailing-list-with-a-non-google-e-mail-address/66411#66411) in order to avoid joining the group with a gmail account (or associating my email address with a google account). I tried adding the email I want to join with as alternative email, but that didn't help.

[image]

I cannot search for solutions because typing "Google" into Google can break the internet.

Comment: Have you been trying to do this just today or is this a long-standing problem?  It's not impossible that it is an actual server error.

Comment: @jonsca I happens for more than 24h now.

Comment: I have been having the same problem today and yesterday

Comment: I have just managed to fix it by setting my email address as an Alternative email in my Google Account at https://myaccount.google.com/email (Recovery email or Contact email wasn't sufficient); though I appreciate that this isn't useful for your purposes if you don't want to associate your email address with a Google Account